# PHP script to convert csv to XML not working for large file (around 1GB)

Tags: php, xml, csv

We have written the following PHP script to convert CSV file to XML file. But It got stuck and didn't come out of the while loop to saveXML.

The size of the CSV file is around 1GB, The number of rows in the CSV file is around 1,00,000.

Due to the large number of rows, It is not working.

My question is: How can we modify this following code in such a way that, It works for a large file ?

```
<?php
    $delimit = "," ;        
    $row_count = 0 ;

    $inputFilename = "feed.csv" ;

    $outputFilename   = 'output.xml';
    $inputFile  = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

    $headers = fgetcsv($inputFile);
    $doc  = new DomDocument();
    $doc->formatOutput   = true;

    $root = $doc->createElement('rows');  
    $root = $doc->appendChild($root);     

    while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $container = $doc->createElement('row'); 
        foreach ($headers as $i => $header)
        {
            $arr = explode($delimit, $header);
            foreach ($arr as $j => $ar)
            {           
                $child = $doc->createElement(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","",$ar));
                $child = $container->appendChild($child); 

                $whole = explode($delimit, $row[$i]);
                $value = $doc->createTextNode(ltrim( rtrim($whole[$j], '"') ,'"')); 
                $value = $child->appendChild($value); 
            }
        }
        $root->appendChild($container);
        echo "." ;
    }

    echo "Saving the XML now" ;
    $result = $doc->saveXML();

    echo "Writing to XML file now" ;
    $handle = fopen($outputFilename, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $result);
    fclose($handle);

    return $outputFilename;
```

?>

Edited:

In php.ini the memory_limit and execution time is set for unlimited & maximum. I am executing using command line.

Comment: Do you have PHP displaying errors? Always when developing code, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the script.  Most likely you are exhausting your memory limit. If this is a one-off, you could temporarily increase it.

Comment: Increasing memory limit to 3GB is not an option really. Use http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php instead. I believe if you follow this tutorial http://codeinthehole.com/writing/creating-large-xml-files-with-php/ you can answer the question yourself.

Comment: @Alex Blex, I think, your second link might solve the problem. Let me check it now.

Comment: probably XMLWriter might be the solution over DOM

Comment: Several things are happening here. A very large csv is being read iteratively to a growing xml tree all using two nested `for` loops in a `while` loop. Consider defining headers (xml nodes) outside loop and append csv values in one loop. Please post sample csv/desired xml for demo. There's even an XSLT solution I see of binding several smaller temp docs. This is a good problem. Man, OPs get all the fun!

Answer (score 1):

as you noticed, you run into resource problems with such big in/output.

The input handling you use, `fgetcsv()` is already quite effective as it reads one line at a time.
The output is the problem in this case. You store the whole 1GB raw text into a DOMDocument Object, which adds considerable overhead to the needed memory.

But according to your code, you only write the xml back to a file, so you don't really need it as a DOMDocument at runtime.

The simplest solution would be to build the xml string as a string and write it to the output file for each line of the csv: open the handle for the outputfile with 'a' `(fopen($outputfilename, "a");`, write the xml header before the loop, fwrite every csv-to-xml-ified elment per loop run, write the xml footer after the loop

Answer (score 1):

It's most probably the (mis)usage of the DomDocument that causes your memory issues (as already answered by @cypherabe).

But instead of the proposed string concatenation solution, I would urge you to take a look at the XmlWriter http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php

The XmlWriter extension represents a writer that provides a non-cached, forward-only means of generating streams or files containing XML data. 
This extension can be used in an object oriented style or a procedural one.

It's already bundled with PHP from version 5.2.1

Comment: see my comment to OP.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.prestatraining.com/12-tips-to-optimise-your-php-ini-file-for-prestashop/

Look at the section **Memory and Size Limits** (ignore the fact it's about prestashop)

It sounds like your PHP settings on the server are timing out on execution. If you are trying to process a file that is 1GB I wouldn't be surprised if it fails if you have standard PHP.ini settings.